# Any way to change bluetooth folder?

Tags: bluetooth, directory

I'm looking to change the default bluetooth received files directory in `/home/user/Public`.

Is there a dconf key or some other way to change it?

Answer (score -1):

You can't change it if your device/laptop already have default bluetooth program. Only bluetooth that come with usb adapter can be changed.